# Move uploaded file php not working

Tags: php, upload, imagettftext

I want to move a file that has been created using imagettftext and saved as a png. as you can see, in the code below, i used the move_uploaded_file but to no avail. please help.

tq

```
// Set the content-type
header('Content-Type: image/png');



// Create the image from created image
//$im = imagecreatetruecolor(180, 180);
$im = @imagecreatefromjpeg('poloroid.jpg');

// Create some colors
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$grey = imagecolorallocate($im, 128, 128, 128);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
//imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 399, 29, $white);

// The text to draw
//$text = 'John...';
$fbid = $_POST["id"]; 
$text = $_POST["want"];
$fb_email =$_POST["email"];
$fb_name=$_POST["name"];

$uploads_dir = '/uploaded_files';
// Replace path by your own font path
$font = 'verdana.ttf';

//image file name
$name ="$fbid.png";


// Add some shadow to the text
imagettftext($im, 20, 0,  25, 126, $grey, $font, $text);

// Add the text
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 25, 125, $black, $font, $text);

// Using imagepng() results in clearer text compared with imagejpeg()
//imagepng($im);
imagepng($im,$name,9);
move_uploaded_file($name,"$uploads_dir/$name");
imagedestroy($im);
```

Comment: Remove the `@` symbol from `imagecreatefromjpeg()` and see if you get any errors, also make sure `error_reporting` is on.

Comment: move_uploaded_file move only files uploaded via a form you should use the function [rename](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php)

Answer (score 5):

You are not uploading a file, you are generating one!

`imagepng` has `filename` parameter so you can save it to your drive:

```
$uploads_dir = '/uploaded_files/';
$name = $uploads_dir.$fbid.'.png';
imagepng($im,$name,9);
imagedestroy($im);
```

Comment: okay. i am creating a file. the imagepng($im,$name,9); creates it. so how can i transfer the created file into the uploaded_files folder?

Comment: Exacly like I posted, add the `$uploads_dir` to `$name`, just make sure `upload_dir` is relative to script.

Comment: got this error in the log;

imagepng() [<a href='function.imagepng'>function.imagepng</a>]: Unable to open '/uploaded_files/1279548298.png'

Comment: then `uploaded_files` is not a valid path or a writable directory.

Comment: remove the / before uploaded_files seems to work... Thank you very much Mihai Lorga

Answer (score 1):

try to use `rename`  instead of `move_uploaded_file`